ShortenedThrowableConverter in Spring Boot 3.4 structured logging
In Spring Boot 3.4, structured logging was introduced as a built-in feature. Is it possible to reduce the line length when using this feature with Logstash, especially for exceptions?
For example, consider the following, which was previously formatted like this:
<throwableConverter class="net.logstash.logback.stacktrace.ShortenedThrowableConverter">
  <maxLength>10000</maxLength>
</throwableConverter>

I would prefer not to add more dependencies again
